# Is there a Set Theory textbook which include visual explanation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, soft-question, education

Right now I am taking a class in set theory, The professor in many cases draw a diagram,pic or anything which help you intuitionally understand the material better.

What was surprised me many (at least three) textbook of the Set Theory that I have been looking at it do not have diagrams or any other visual illustrations which help you understand better.

I asked my Professor if he could recommend to me, and his answer is NO. He said there is no Set Theory Textbook which include diagrams or other visual explanations which help improve your intuition about the subject. He even told me that this is the reason that till now he have no favorite textbook for his class, and why each year he chooses a different one.

Edit:-
I am using the book ( Set Theory by Andras Hajnal, Peter Hamburger). This book introductory to set theory but even there is no one Diagram or any other visual explanation.

Comment: This is, partially, why Set Theory pwns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Textbooks for visual learners](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299876/textbooks-for-visual-learners)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the book "Book of Proof" of Richard Hammack in [this](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/BookOfProof.pdf) link; it have many diagrams and pics. But it is not focus in set theory until the last chapters. The chapter about cardinals is very educational.

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned up, because links can go stale. Give thet title and author in the answer.

Comment: Thanks,Most of the book that deal with basic definition of set theory you can find diagram or illustration .But the problem in most advanced they stop giving diagram. this book maybe useful for first year undergraduate student.But what I am look at is a set theory for advanced undergraduate or first year graduate student.thanks again

Comment: I understand. But the advanced topics of Set theory are very unintuitive. For instance, I remember a question about the intuition behind the Zorn's lemma, but this intuition is difficult to explain, if it exists. :-)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Corrected, thanks! :-)

Comment: Sorry,maybe I supposed to not use the work "advanced". lets say any elementary set textbook. for example when I look at definition of Axiom of Choice in wikipedia,they give an visual illustration, while in book I use ( Set Theory by Andras Hajnal & Peter Hamburger ) there is no even single one visual explanation.